# Cursor pointer causes flickers on iPad

Tags: css, angularjs

I came across an issue while running my web on an iPad. The ipad wouldn't raise a click even when I make a touch on the screen.

I overcame this by applying the following css on the html body:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Now when I touch away it detects the touch as a click event. However This causes the screen to flicker.

The following shows what I mean :

```css
.div2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <p>
    div one has no flicker
  </p>
</div>

<div class="div2">
  <p>
    This one flickers when clicked on a touch screen or device mode on chrome
  </p>
</div>
```

How would I resolve this sideffect? or is there any alternative? I would like to avoid much jQuery/javascript as possible.

Comment: please provide your css markup + code to reproduce the issue. could be an issue with `z-index`/etc but we can't say withouy a working demo

Comment: The markup I provided above recreates the issue. If you copy it to a html file and run it on a touch screen or in device mode on chrome it will show the issue. @Professor.CSS

Comment: I am unable to reproduce. Also, you are aware there isn't actually a cursor on an ipad, right?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
    .div2{
      cursor:default;
    }
}
```

Comment: That prevents the click events from triggering at all

Comment: Does cursor:default fix the issue?

Comment: Doesn't seem to have fixed the issue